# corresponding template for an action doesn't get executed

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have a code in which I assign a few variables and then the corresponding template is called and displayed. But in one of the cases, the controller doesn't reach the template and I get an  error

> The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.Please try again later.

I have tried to debug it, and found that the code always reaches untill the last line of the action whereas the template isn't shown.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Show us some code, action, template, etc ..

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the page through dev environment. Just add frontend_dev.php or whatever your application is called to the host that you have.

Example: yourdomain/frontend_dev.php/module/action.

With this you can see the exact error that you have.

Comment: there isn't any error coming over there
Just the above message